# Error: report filters

Tags: visualforce, api, json

problem, i try to dynamically filter a report but i get an error.

The apex code to set the filter dynamically based on some conditions:

```
  filtre ='column:\'account.name\',operator:\'equals\', value:\'{us.name}\'';
```

and here the visualforce code:

```
<analytics:reportChart reportId="00Ob0000003nlBt" size="small" cacheResults="false" filter="{!filtre}" ></analytics:reportChart>
```

here is the error:

[image]

it's in french , here is the translation:

> "Insert filter attributes with a valid JSON format."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm) on `analytics:reportChart`, it looks like your JSON format needs to be `List<Object>`, so it should look like:

```
filtre = '[{column:\'account.name\',operator:\'equals\', value:\'{us.name}\'}]';
```